# Android achartengine drawing line chart with multiple series

Tags: android, achartengine

I am trying to develop an application with achart engine which draws a chart with multiple series . 
Here is my code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class Graph {
    private Context context;
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset;
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer;
    public static boolean ClickEnabled = true;
    public Graph(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void initData(ArrayList<Double> x,ArrayList<Double> y,ArrayList<Double> z){      
        XYSeries seriesX = new XYSeries("X");
        for(int i =0 ; i< x.size();i++){
            seriesX.add(x.get(i), i);
        }
        XYSeries seriesY = new XYSeries("Y");
        for(int i =0 ; i< y.size();i++){
            seriesY.add(y.get(i), i);
        }
        XYSeries seriesZ = new XYSeries("Z");
        for(int i =0 ; i< z.size();i++){
            seriesZ.add(z.get(i), i);
        }
        dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(seriesX);
        dataset.addSeries(seriesY);
        dataset.addSeries(seriesZ);
        renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    }
    public void setProperties(){
        renderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
        renderer.setClickEnabled(ClickEnabled);
        renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        renderer.setChartTitle("AccelerometerData");
        renderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer1.setColor(Color.RED);
        renderer1.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer1);
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        renderer2.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer3 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer3.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        renderer3.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer3);
    }


    public GraphicalView getGraph(){    
        return ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, dataset, renderer);
    }
}
```

I am getting a chart like this:
[image]

I want all three series parallelly and want to remove black background from chart;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Change the black color you can do like this

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] { top, left, bottom, right });
    renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.RED);
```

and for your second problem plz be more specific by screenshot or any refrence image.